# Is there any way to find matches between longer and smaller word using agrep() fct

Tags: r

I want to define that there is a match when there is an element, in a longer string, in a smaller string.

E.g.

`String1 <- "Hey you"
String2 <- "you"`

This is a match because the element you from String1 is also part in String2.

However, this does not work when using the `agrep()` function.

`agrep(String1,String2)`

Is there any way to do this using the function? Maybe by means of word boundaries?

Comment: You can change the parameters, `agrep(String1,String2, max= list(cost = 0.5))#[1] 1`

Comment: Works. But can you explain what exactly it does? Does it simply increase the tolerance of difference between the two strings?

Comment: If the other way is what you wanted `grep(String2, String1)` also works.  Based on the solution with `str_detect`

Answer (score 2):

If you are not limited to the function `agrep`, `str_detect` from `stringr` would solve this as well:

```
String1 <- "Hey you"
String2 <- "you"


stringr::str_detect(string = String1, pattern = String2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I was hoping there is a way to use agrep combined with word boundaries like \b or sth